# ImportError: No module named scitools.std

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, scitools

I installed Anaconda, but now that I wanted to use StringFunction in scitools.std I get error: ImportError: No module named scitools.std! So I did this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-scitools
```

Still didn't work. How can I help my computer "find scitools"?

Thank you for your time.

Kind regards,
Marius

Comment: try scipy.std instead.

Comment: "from scipy.std import StringFunction" returns "ImportError: No module named std". "from scipy import StringFunction" returns "ImportError: cannot import name StringFunction". What do you think? Thanks.M

Comment: What happen if you try to simply import scitools? and it should be `from scitools.StringFunction import StringFunction`. If you have anaconda install you should be able to get it by calling `conda install scitools`

Comment: "from scitools.StringFunction import StringFunction" => "ImportError: No module named scitools.StringFunction". And "from scitools import StringFunction" => "ImportError: No module named scitools". And "conda install scitools" => "Error: No packages found matching: scitools.std"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apt-get install` is going to install it into the system Python, not the Anaconda Python. You need to use `conda` to install packages into Anaconda.

There isn't an official scitools build for Anaconda, but I've built one and put it on binstar (I'm assuming you are using Python 2.7, 64-bit Linux). `conda install -c asmeurer scitools` will get it.

Comment: its no longer working

Answer (score 0):

In anaconda:

`conda install --channel johannr scitools`

ref to :
[hplgit/scitools: Additional scientific computing functionality in Python - extensions to NumPy/SciPy++](https://github.com/hplgit/scitools)

Answer (score 0):

For Python3, Use scitools3 instead

```
pip install scitools3
```

See also: [wikis of scitools](https://code.google.com/archive/p/scitools/wikis/Installation.wiki) and [pypi of scitools3](https://pypi.org/project/scitools3/)