# Python 2.7 Anaconda Spyder IDE Scitools Movie encoder='html' Not Working

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, spyder, encoder

Right now, I'm trying to create a movie in the Anaconda Spyder IDE (running Python 2.7). I have the following import statement at the top of my program:

```
from scitools.std import cos, exp, linspace, plot, movie
import time, glob, sys, os
```

After creating plots to make a movie from, I use the call:

```
movie('tmp_*.png', encoder='html', output_file='tmp_heatwave.html')
```

to try and create a movie in .html format.  After running my program, I get the error:

```
ValueError: encoder must be ['mencoder', 'ffmpeg', 'mpeg_encode', 'ppmtompeg',
'mpeg2enc', 'convert'], not 'html'
```

Why is this happening? According to my textbook, *A Primer on Scientific Programming with Python*, "The HTML format can always be made and played. Hence, this format is the natural choice if problems with other formats occur."

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of `scitools` are you using? 0.9.0?

In the source code of `movie` class, `html` is in the legal encoder.

```
...
_legal_encoders = 'convert mencoder ffmpeg mpeg_encode ppmtompeg '\
                  'mpeg2enc html'.split()
_legal_file_types = 'png gif jpg ps eps bmp tif tga pnm'.split()
...
```

EDIT:

check version of `scitools`.

```
>>> import scitools
>>> scitools.__version__
'0.9.0'
>>>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to check the version number. I downloaded scitools onto Spyder using the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368393/importerror-no-module-named-scitools-std. Would that result in html not being a legal encoder?

Comment: @sk3644 You can use scitools.__version__ to check version info.

Comment: I'm getting the following:                                      >>> scitools._version_
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'scitools' is not defined
>>> scitools.__version__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'scitools' is not defined

Comment: >>> scitools.__version__
'0.8'

Comment: does that mean .html encoding is not available? If so, how can I get it?

Comment: @sk3644 Here you can get the latest version and re-install it. https://code.google.com/p/scitools/downloads/list

Comment: Thanks. I installed the update, however, entering "python setup.py install" on the command-line gives an invalid syntax warning. What command do I need to enter?

Comment: @sk3644 I use the same command as you and it worked. I'm on window 7 64bit.